# How to declare java server (jetty) email service?

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp

I'm using Spring mail service for sending emails from my server.
However, how can I make sure that the server host (which run in the user environment) have running SMTP server?

By default, the Spring server user port 25 on the localhost.
Should I get the SMTP configuration from the user when he install my server or there is more friendly way to send emails?

Comment: Most likely Spring will throw some exception, it the host:port pair is not SMTP server.

Comment: Yes, its throw connection exception, but the problem is that I don't know what will be the smtp server properties in my user environment.

Comment: maybe there is API (linux) that return this properties...

Comment: :) You'd better ask users for configuration.

Comment: I guess so, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bean like this and add it to your application context file..

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host"><value>smtp.gmail.com</value></property>
    <property name="port"><value>587</value></property>
    <property name="protocol"><value>smtp</value></property>
    <property name="username" value="YOUR-MAIL-ID-HERE" />
    <property name="password" value="YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">25000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and you should probalbly use a template engine like `Thymeleaf`(see [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org)) to set the content of email in a separate file..

hope this helps..

Comment: thanks! but in my case I want to use my user smtp server that exists (if exists) is his farm (I guess my users have also firewall so I won't be able to connect other third party smtp servers (e.g. gmail)). So the question here is: can I have elegant way to found what are my user farm smtp server properties and inject them to my mailSender properties?

Comment: See this post "Property settings in spring-beans.xml at compile time" answered by mark http://www.coderanch.com/t/450158/Spring/Property-settings-spring-beans-xml</a>..might be wat u r looking for..